# all possible combinations of items dependent on condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a database containing info on purchase histories of different customers.
I want to obtain item pairs of product that were bought "together" by a customer within a week but not on the same day. Basically a customer who came on Monday and bought item 1 and item 2 and then came back on Tuesday and bought item 3. 
I currently have the information about what customer bought which item at what date. Each transaction has its own row.

In the end I would like to have the two pairs: item 1 & item 3 and item2 & item3. For every customer.

Checking for people who bought item1 & item3 is one thing, but also checking if that happened within a specific timeframe leaves me struggling.

The data is in an Oracle database.

Every help is appreciated!
Database and desired result looks like this approx:
[image: Database]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, sample data and desired results are helpful.

Comment: I did, thanks for the input

Answer (score 1):

Please indicate your precise Oracle database version in future questions.

If you have version 12c or later, "row pattern matching" was designed to do this kind of thing:

```
with data (customer, trans_date, purchase) as (
  select 'C1', date '2019-08-01', 'Item1' from dual union all
  select 'C1', date '2019-08-01', 'Item2' from dual union all
  select 'C2', date '2019-08-01', 'Item4' from dual union all
  select 'C2', date '2019-08-03', 'Item5' from dual union all
  select 'C1', date '2019-08-04', 'Item3' from dual
)
select * from data
match_recognize(
  partition by customer order by trans_date, purchase
  measures first(trans_date) first_trans_date, first(purchase) first_purchase
  all rows per match
  after match skip to next row
  pattern({-A+-} B+)
  define a as trans_date = first(trans_date),
    b as trans_date <= first(trans_date) + 7
);

CU TRANS_DATE          PURCH FIRST_TRANS_DATE    FIRST
-- ------------------- ----- ------------------- -----
C1 2019-08-04 00:00:00 Item3 2019-08-01 00:00:00 Item1
C1 2019-08-04 00:00:00 Item3 2019-08-01 00:00:00 Item2
C2 2019-08-03 00:00:00 Item5 2019-08-01 00:00:00 Item4
```

The "A" rows are the ones that were purchased on the same day, the "B" rows were purchased later that week. By saying "after match skip to next row", I can handle multiple "A" rows one at a time. This is much more efficient than a self join.

Best regards,
Stew Ashton

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self-join:

```
with cid as (
      select distinct customer, purchase, trunc(trans_date) as pdate
      from t
     )
select cid1.customer, cid1.item, cid2.item
from cid cid1 join
     cid cid2
     on cid1.customer = cid2.customer and
        cid1.purchase <> cid2.purchase and
        cid2.pdate > cid.pdate and
        cid2.pdate < cid.pdate + interval '7' day;
```

This returns items in the order they were purchased.